# How to handle form data in html page using asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, handler

Sometimes I have the need to handle data from a contact form of a html only website, with hosting restrictions, not capable of running asp.net code.

How can I hadle the data in this situation ? (in simpler cases, send an e-mail)

Comment: The intention to provide information is good however this isn't how StackOverflow works. You provide answer to someone who asks for it. Maybe try this on a blog or something?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I usually redirect the data to an asp.net handler (hosted on another server running asp.net).

Here is how I do it:

The html form:

```
        <form name="ajax-form" id="ajax-form" action="http://somedomain.com/handler.ashx" method="post">
            <label for="name">
                Nome: *
                <span class="error" id="err-name">please enter your name</span>
            </label>
            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" />
            <label for="email">
                E-Mail: *
                <span class="error" id="err-email">please enter your e-mail</span>
                <span class="error" id="err-emailvld">the e-mail does not have a valid format</span>
            </label>
            <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            <div id="button-con"><button class="send_message" id="send">Send</button></div>
            <div class="error text-align-center" id="err-form">Error on form. Please check!</div>
            <div class="error text-align-center" id="err-timedout">Time out connecting to server...</div>
            <div class="error" id="err-state"></div>
        </form>
```

After loading jquery I add this javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#send').click(function(){ 
        $('.error').fadeOut('slow'); 

        var error = false; 

        var name = $('input#name').val(); 
        if(name == "" || name == " ") {
            $('#err-name').fadeIn('slow'); 
            error = true; 
        }

        var email_compare = /^([a-z0-9_.-]+)@([da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})$/; 
        var email = $('input#email').val(); 
        if (email == "" || email == " ") { 
            $('#err-email').fadeIn('slow'); 
            error = true;
        }else if (!email_compare.test(email)) { 
            $('#err-emailvld').fadeIn('slow'); 
            error = true;
        }

        if(error == true) {
            $('#err-form').slideDown('slow');
            return false;
        }

        var obj = {};
        obj.name = name;
        obj.email = email;
        obj.message = $("#message").val();

        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);

        console.log(jsonData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $('#ajax-form').attr('action'),
            data: jsonData,
            timeout: 6000,
            error: function(request,error) {
                if (error == "timeout") {
                    $('#err-timedout').slideDown('slow');
                }
                else {
                    $('#err-state').slideDown('slow');
                    $("#err-state").html('An error occurred: ' + error + '');
                }
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#ajax-form').slideUp('slow');
                $('#ajaxsuccess').slideDown('slow');
            }
        });

        return false; 
    });
});
```

And finnaly, the code for my handler.ashx:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Handler" %>

Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.IO

Public Class Handler : Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"

        Try
            Dim strJson As String = New StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()
            Dim objUsr As userInfo = Deserialize(Of userInfo)(strJson)

            If objUsr IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim name As String = objUsr.name
                Dim email As String = objUsr.email
                Dim message As String = objUsr.message

                'here you treat you data, some send email function using the data collected
                context.Response.Write(String.Format("Name :{0} , email={1}, message={2}", name, email, message))
            Else
                context.Response.Write("No Data")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            context.Response.Write("Error :" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Class userInfo
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property email As String
        Public Property message As String
    End Class

    Public Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal context As String) As T
        Dim jsonData As String = context
        Dim obj = CType(New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of T)(jsonData), T)
        Return obj
    End Function

End Class
```

I hope this can be useful for you...